# Column is of type Boolean but expression is of type text Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

Can anyone help me with the error?

```
Update table 
SET
tentative = case src.tentative 
WHEN 1 THEN 't' ELSE 'f' END
FROM table
```

Comment: what is your exact question?

Comment: I'm trying to update a column. Tentative is of boolean type but on the source side it is varchar. I'm getting this issue while casting.

Comment: You appear to be trying to cast from a boolean to a character ... do you perhaps mean to do `WHEN 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`?

Answer (score 12):

Your column `tentative` is a `BOOLEAN` type; however, you are trying to update it with a `TEXT` type value.

All you need to do is use `BOOLEAN` in your update like so:

```
UPDATE table 
SET tentative = CASE src.tentative WHEN 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
FROM src_table src;
```

Alternatively, but maybe less obvious you can do this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET tentative = (src.tentative = 1)
FROM src_table src;
```

Comment: 't' and 'f' are valid literals of TRUE and FALSE